# Any explorer.exe argument to open windows explorer at specific position(top,left) and size(width,height)?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, process

I need to set Windows Explorer instances in a specific positioning and size. I was hoping to accomplish that by passing arguments to the executable at opening. However I didn't find anything related to that.

Any directions?